# How to make my program output its first value

Tags: java, methods, do-while

My program should output numbers into words. For example input 10. Output TEN. ALL of the other numbers I enter come out right except for ten. I just need help to fix that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. When i enter 10 it comes out as a blank.

MY CODE:

Comment: It is jusdt one output that I need help on

Comment: oh men use loops and  string array please.Will take less space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why your program outputs the number in words correctly for all numbers between 11-99 and not for 10 is because you forgot the following code in your *teens()* subroutine:

```
if(numInput==10){
      System.out.println("Ten");
}
```

When the input is '10', that subroutine will be entered, but it will not output anything because you never check if the input is '10'.

Also, the following code in the *tens()* subroutine:

```
if(tensDigit==10){
     System.out.println("ten");
}
```

Can never be reached, since when the output is '10', the *teens()* subroutine is called, not the *tens()* subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `if(numInput == 10) { System.out.println("Ten");}` to `teens(double numInput)`.
2. Why use `double`? I'd use `int`.
3. In `double tensDigit = Math.floor((numInput % 100) / 10)`, remove `% 100`, since you've already done a sanity check.
4. Remove `if(tensDigit == 10)` from `public static void tens(double tensDigit)`.
5. Change `tryAgain` and `error` to `boolean`.
6. Work on indentation.

Comment: @Daemon No it's not. It SHOULD be the answer, but if you look at the code in the question, the tens() routine is only entered for numbers equal to or above 20. If the number is between 10 and 19 (inclusive), the teens() routine is entered instead.

Comment: This is incorrect. The way the program is calculating it, 10 is being treated as a "teen"

Comment: @AdamSmith Apologies. It seemed right, but after testing it still didn't fix the issue. Seems that I'm still waking up.

Comment: @Daemon No problem, just wanted to point it out since the way that piece of code is written doesn't make it obvious.

Answer (score 0):

In your Tens() method... you have:

```
if (tensDigit==10)
{  
    System.out.println("ten");  
}
```

it needs to be:

```
if(tensDigit==1)
{  
    System.out.println("ten");  
}
```

Comment: See Mitesh Pathak's answer's comments to see why this is incorrect.

Comment: You only call Tens() if it's greater than equal to 20, otherwise you are only calling TEENS()

Answer (score 0):

You only call Tens() if it's greater than equal to 20, otherwise you are only calling TEENS(), so when you enter 10 it makes sense why Tens() is not being called...